# how to reassign single cell value in 2D python array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to change the value of one cell in a 2D python array:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

which I generated from

```
m=3*[[0]*3]
for y in xrange(0,3):
    for x in xrange(0,3):
        m[y][x]=x
```

I want to replace m[0][0] with 5 so that it looks like

```
[[5, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

but instead it is

```
[[5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2], [5, 1, 2]]
```

when i use

```
m[0][0]=5
```

what's going on?

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate; multiplication as in `m=3*[[0]*3]` doesn't work like you think it does. :-)

Comment: @DSM thanks. what do i do with a question when there's a duplicate?

Comment: No need to do anything!  I linked this question to the other, so now anyone who describes the problem using the same words you did will have an easier time finding an answer.

Comment: this question gets worded a new way every time because theres no way to know whats happening the first time you encounter it